# Java creates temp folder with shortened path and throws 'Not found' exception when trying to access files placed in it

Tags: java, windows, groovy

so I did run into one very weird issue. The idea is simple: create temp dir, place  some files in it and then try to access them. Now the problem is that calling `File.createTempDir()` or `Files.createTempDirectory(prefix)` creates new file inside `AppData/Local/temp` with shortened path, so the full path to folder looks something like `C:/Users/FirstNam~1/AppData/Local/Temp/myFolder/myFile.txt` instead of `C:/Users/FirstName LastName/AppData/Local/Temp/myFolder.myFile.txt`.

The difference is that generated path inside java contains `FirstNam~1` instead of `FistName SecondName`. Java then throws exception `File Not Found`.
When I try to copy and paste shortened path into file explorer I get an error saying that file does not exist, but if I do change shortened path to full one then file opens and it works as intended.

Is there any way to fix it? Ether by forcing java to use full path names or enabling something in windows? I did Enable NTFS long paths policy, but it did not help.

This is happening when using java 8/11 and windows 10 running on VM, project is using AGP and gradle. Temp file is created inside groovy file that `extends Plugin<Project>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just when I lose hope and create a ticket, couple hours after that I find the answer. So, java has method `Path.toRealPath()` which solves this `~1` issue. After using this method paths no longer contain shortening and are correctly resolved.

EDIT: looks like java is doing everything correct and paths are actually valid, problem did come from library that I'm using and it's a bug with it.